# OpenCV changes the typing of function across platforms?

Tags: python, opencv

On my laptop, the following code snippit runs, but on a Raspberry Pi it does not. On both systems `img` contains a successfully loaded bgr image. My laptop uses python 2.7.6, my Pi uses python 2.7.3.

```
gout = gimg = cv2.inRange(img, (0, 110, 0), (100, 255, 100))
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array
```

Comment: According to the official documentaton cv2.inRang does not return anything in Python? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html (see inRange)